# Permit URL request based on mask

Tags: spring, security

I wan to configure Spring Security to allow request based on mask:

```
/{localization}/payment/{transaction_id}
```

Is this correct?

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/*/payment/*").permitAll().anyRequest().permitAll();
```

Or I need to use this?

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**/payment/**").permitAll().anyRequest().permitAll();
```

Which one should I use?

Answer (score 0):

The first one is sufficient if you don't need more directories int the path.

- `*` matches zero or more characters
- `**` matches zero or more
  directories in a path

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html